# What is the best way to go about matching proton-NMR spectra to molecules?

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I've attatched an example question.[image] I have already solved this one, I'm wondering about what, in your experience, is the most time-efficient way of approaching a question like this one. I can solve these questions backwards pretty decently (ie If I know the solutions, then I can justify them in pretty decent detail) but when it comes to deciding on which spectrum is assigned to which molecule, I find that it takes me ages. Is there any 'standard approach' that I should be aware of, or is it simply a matter of practice?

Comment: You said you have already solved this one. So, show your work and we direct you to better way if your work is longer than needed. This is not hard as you think it is.

Comment: The compounds with vinylic and methyl protons are a good place to start (B,G,E,3), that should be relatively easy. Also, look for symmetry. C should also be simple.

Comment: Where are you studying chemistry, do they *teach* there, or just expect you to somehow turn into accomplished chemist? ;))